# C# get network connection status and speed in XP

Tags: c#, windows-xp, networking

how can I get the connection statues and speed in windows XP?

Comment: You mean your network connection status (connected, disconnected etc..) and the speed of the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should tell you if a network is available.

```
bool IsAvailable = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```

Gets the speed of the network

```
long NetworkSpeed = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.Speed;
```

See here for other things you can use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(v=VS.100).aspx